How to access old and 'keep forever' builds in Jenkins?
In Jenkins, we usually mark release jobs and to be kept forever, but the normal Jenkins UI doesn't seem to allow access to them. At least, I can't see them in the build history of the job's page. How to access them?
Note that the question List all keep-forever builds in Jenkins? seems similar, but it's more about retrieving all 'keep forever' builds of all jobs in one list.

The Jenkins UI does in fact provide a way to access these older jobs, but it's not easily discoverable, because the option is hidden until you hover over the build list. When you do, a navigation panel pops up with up and down arrows.
1
Click the down arrow to page through the build history towards the older builds.
Note that (at least at the time of this writing) the navigation  always appears in the top area of the build history, so when you have scrolled down to the end of the list, you may not be able to see it because it appeared outside the visible area.
This feature might seem obvious to some users, but others (like me) have spent too much time to find it...
